Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log(2e^{x}-1)}{e^{x}-1}dx$?
Evaluate $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log(2e^{x}-1)}{e^{x}-1}dx$$ ?
This question is from MIT BEE Finals 2024
What I tried so far :
I wrote the integral as $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{x}\log(2e^{x}-1)}{e^{x}(e^{x}-1)}dx$$
That is I multiplied both the numerator and denominator by $e^{x}$
Now I substituted $e^{x}=t$ which implies $e^{x}dx=dt$
$\implies I=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\log(2t-1)}{t(t-1)}dt$
Now I wrote the numerator as $[t-(t-1)]$
$\implies I=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\log(2t-1)}{(t-1)}dt-\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\log(2t-1)}{t}dt$
Now I can't understand how to integrate these $2$ integrals.
$1^{st}$ :$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\log(2t-1)}{(t-1)}dt$
$2^{nd}$ :$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\log(2t-1)}{t}dt$
Please help me out with this integral.
Best Wishes
Mathematics

Those remaining integrals can be evaluated in terms of the dilogarithm, but that's almost definitely not the expected method for this problem. On the other hand, substituting $y=2e^x-1$ transforms your integral to a more well-known one.

Please explain me in detail @user170231. I found only this method

Really it was a difficult integral

A user asked the same question so please feel free to view them in this link.

Substitute $2e^x-1=u^{-1}$ and use geometric series
$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(2e^x-1)}{e^x-1}dx=-2\int_0^1\frac{\ln u}{1-u^2}dx$$
$$=-2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^1u^{2n}\ln (u)du=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}=2\left(\frac{\pi^2}{8}\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{4}$$

You can split the integrals because both diverge.
Starting from $I=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\log(2t-1)}{t(t-1)}dt$ replace $t=u^{-1}$ to achieve
$$
I
{
=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(2/u-1)}{1-u}du
\\=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(2-u)}{1-u}-\frac{\log(u)}{1-u}du
\\=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1+u)}{u}-\frac{\log(u)}{1-u}du
\\=\text{Li}_2(1)-\text{Li}_2(-1)
\\=\frac{\pi^2}{4}.
}
$$

Mention what is $Li_2$ stands for

It is the dilogarithm function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilogarithm
